# fiddler, webclient response header from downloadfileasync in C#

Tags: c#, .net, webclient, fiddler

I realized a website cheats me and has two download links.

I acquire the first download link no problem...but here is the situation.

Upon clicking the hyperlink to download (the url which I acquire), they have a response header with a TRANSPORT LOCATION value?url? that is the actual download link/url.

```
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(uri, _root + _name + ".mp3");
```

The following code above crashes with a error of

> THE REMOTE SERVER RETURNED A 403 FORBIDDEN ERROR

This whole time I believed it had to do with user-agents, etc, but it does not.

What happens is that when I try to download, upon using Fiddler (ty stackoverflow so far...), there is a response header with the actual URL!

How do I acquire the actual URL?

In fiddler, I found that it is a RESPONSE HEADER that under the text 'TRANSPORT',

there is essentially `Connection: keep-alive & Location: {DOWNLOAD URL}`

How do I grab the location text which is the url?

So my question really is,

HOW DO I GET THE RESPONSE HEADER LOCATION TEXT AFTER DOWNLOADFILEASYNC FAILS (returns 403 forbidden error under webexception e) AS IT IS A RESPONSE HEADER ?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to read the response headers when you use the `DownloadFileAsync` API. Instead, use a normal `HTTPWebRequest` and then just read the headers from that response instead.

Comment: can I still use webclient with httpwebrequest? I need to remove the savedialog...hold up I will test!

Comment: The idea is that you'd use the `HttpWebRequest` to retrieve the target Url, then use that Url with the WebClient. Which should work, unless the server is rejecting the WebClient's requests because it doesn't like the `User-Agent` header or something like that.